# Como puedo añadir un registro y que detecte que ya hay una fila existente y me lo reemplace por el que ya esta

Tags: c#, datatable

en la cual ingreso el codigo, nombre y costo y se agrega abajo el registro, lo que quisiera es que al momento de poner el mismo codigo y ejemplo cambiar el costo que inmediatamente el costo me lo reemplace por el registro ya existente, y que no me haga doble fila.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
   function ProductoGuardar() {
        var Bodega = {
            ProductoFila: $("#txtIdProducto").val(),
            ProductoCodigo: $("#txtCodigo").val(),
            ProductoNombre: $("#txtDescripcion").val(),
            ProductoCostoActual: $("#txtCostoActual").val(),
            ProductoCantidad: $("#txtCantidad").val(),
            Descuento: $("#txtDescuento").val(),
            ProductoTotal: $("#txtCostoActual").val() * $("#txtCantidad").val() - $("#txtDescuento").val(),
        }
        ///Guardo el siguiente valor en la caja te texto txtIdProducto
        var Fila = parseInt($("#txtIdProducto").val()) + 1;
        $("#txtIdProducto").val(Fila);
```

> Dejo imagen de referencia, me registra 2 filas extras y yo quisiera que en el mismo
> registro hiciera el cambio y no que me agregue filas extras.
>
> Ese boton lo que hace es bajar los campos que introduje, cod, nombre, costo, cantidad etc a la parte de abajo

> Esa funcion yo la llamo al boton que les muestro (+) lo que quisiera es que al presionar, revisara si ya existe alguna fila con el mismo codigo y que no me permita añadir otra fila con el mismo codigo si no que unicamente bajar los campos de costo actual cantidad y descuento a la parte de abajo y que los reemplace.

Comment: Debes editar tu pregunta agregando el código para que podamos verlo y brindarte una solución

Comment: ya @EvilFearzZ ya edite mi pregunta